# Mailpoet Daemon Trigger Issues

Tags: cron

I'm getting hundreds of these failed actions appear daily [see image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA4XR.png)

The thing is, I'm not using Mailpoet on my wordpress site, so I'm not sure why these scheduled actions are even trying to be processed.

Does anyone know how I might be able to fix this?

Thanks!

Basic - just reconfirmed that Mailpoet wasn't installed on the site.